# Is there a BB tool that has the Park BBT-69.2 16-notch pattern but can be used with a BB with spindles?

Tags: bottom-bracket, tools

My BB spindle is bottoming-out against the inner wall of the BBT-69.2 even though the spindle is a short one, 103mm; so I would like to find a 3/8 square drive BB tool with the same 16-notch pattern but with a taller height, not dome-like but more conical in its shape. Is there such a tool that can be used with a 3/8 drive torque wrench like the Park TW-2?   I don't have enough experience to know by feel when things are properly torqued and prefer to rely on the manufacturer's torque specs. Or are the only 16-notch choices available the hand wrenches, e.g. the Park BBT-9, where you have to go by feel?

[image: JIS Square Taper BB with 16-notch cups]

[image: spindle bottoming out]

Comment: Is the spindle stuck? What's keeping it from smacking through?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. I'm trying to install the BB. It's an old-school square-taper BB but with a 16-notch (external) cup.  I will add a picture.

Comment: I think the BikeHand YC-29BB-2A might work. It is cylindrical rather than dome-shaped, so the spindle might not bottom out. It is a weird hybrid. You can just go by feel or use a torque wrench with a 1/2 drive.

Answer (score 4):

I see you found a tool that works, I just wanted to add that they do make wrenches that also have a 3/8" driver hole to be used with a torque wrench. I like these as it gives you a couple options. The example here is a Pedro's but there are other brands that make them as well.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the 3/8 option!

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the tool I found after asking the question, the BikeHand YC-29BB-2A, does indeed work with square taper BBs that have 16-notch external cups.  It got a good purchase on the notched cup so I was able to torque the drive side to 60Nm and the NDS to 40Nm.

The cylinder of the tool is quite deep, so there's no bottoming out of the spindle against the inner wall, and a torque wrench with a 1/2 drive can be used with it. It can also be used to tighten the BB by feel, with the handle.

There also appears to be a socket-only version without a handle, YC-29BB, which I assume takes a 1/2 drive as well, although none of the descriptions I've found online saw fit to mention the driver size.